# CEH training courses requirements

Tags: professional-education, certification

What are the requirements for studying CEH?

Is there any requirements for the programming background?
And can anyone apply for it or does he has to have a recommendation for both studying and taking the test.

Comment: I would argue that all you need is a sound knowledge of how systems work: OS's, TCP/IP (and maybe a couple of protocols), and, of course, people. People are nearly always the weakest link.

Answer (score 1):

I have the CEH certification.

First, please read the official [FAQ](https://www.eccouncil.org/ceh-frequently-asked-questions).

The CEH is pretty basic and covers pre-made tools for hacking and penetration testing, which means that you could pass the exam without a lot of pre-knowledge of anything. That said, you will have a much easier time (and you would be a much more effective CEH) if you did understand the basics of TCP, DNS, and operating systems.

Info Security is a wide area of study and you will never stop learning. Start somewhere and keep pushing in areas that interest you.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements**: Good Knowledge of **TCP-IP** and the basic knowledge of operating systems, which Windows and **Linux**. For programming you must know the basic concepts.
I recommend you the use of **Linux's terminal** for learn commands and apply the theory that you have studied. You can found many documents on these arguments.